# Sonata admin/swiftmailer how to take back information from the list

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, swiftmailer

I am currently trying to use swiftmailer in my project. I am currently working on Sonata Admin and I wanted to know how I could retrieve the object displayed in a list to be able to retrieve the associated mail addresses and thus send an e-mail to all the addresses contained in this list. I want to go through the list displayed by sonata because their filter system works very well and I would use it to choose the people I want to send an email to. I saw on the symfony documentation that it was possible to send mail to an address table in this form:

```
$to = array('one@example.com', 'two@example.com', 'three@example.com');

$message = (new \Swift_Message('Hello Email'))
    ->setFrom('send@example.com')
            ->setTo(array($to))
            ->setBody('html content goes here', 'text/html');

$mailer->send($message);
```

But i don't know how to take back the object form the list.
From this grid.

[image: grid]
Can you help me thanks ?

Ps : 
I just think putting a button down the list to send an email to all the people displayed in the list.

Thanks a lot.

Edit : 
I'm still searching and i found that the sql request was like 't0.id' and 'c0.id'. t0 and c0 are the name of the object ? Is it always that ? What is the difference between t0 and c0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding an action to your admin list.
        To do so, first create a new class in `YourAdminBundle\Controller` folder, extending `Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController`.

Your custom action could look like this for instance :

```
  /** @property YourAdminClass $admin */
        public function batchActionSendMail(ProxyQueryInterface $selectedModelQuery ,$type = 'sendMails') {

       if (false === $this->admin->isGranted('EDIT')) {
             throw new AccessDeniedException();
        }

           /* selected objects in your list !! */
            $selectedModels = $selectedModelQuery->execute();

            try{
             foreach ($selectedModels as $selectedModel){
              // your code to retrieve objects mails here (for instance)
                }
               //code to send your mails

                }
               catch(\Exception $e)
                {
                  $this->addFlash('sonata_flash_error', "error");
                }
                 $this->addFlash('sonata_flash_success', 'mails sent')  

         return new RedirectResponse($this->admin->generateUrl('list'));
            }
```

To make this custom CRUD controller active, go to `services.yml`, get to your class admin block, and complete the third param of `arguments` property by referencing your custom CRUD controller:

```
arguments: [null, YourBundle\Entity\YourEntity,YourAdminBundle:CustomCRUD]
```

Finally, to allow you to use your custom action, go to your Admin Class and add this function  :

```
public function getBatchActions()
    {
       if ($this->hasRoute('edit')) {

                $actions['sendMails'] = array(
                    'label'            => $this->trans('batch.sendMails.action'),
                    'ask_confirmation' => true, // by default always true
                );
            }
      return $actions;  
    }
```

The action will be available in the dropdown list at the bottom of your admin list, next to the "Select all" checkbox.